# WatchKit Glance group gets covered up

Tags: watchkit, xcode-storyboard

Setting up my interface for a Watch glance, and the top group is getting cut off by the bottom group:

[image]

Here's how it's set up in interface builder:

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure why it's getting cut off  / covered up by the other group?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the upper and lower default look of your Glance, but I do not believe you can size the upper and lower sections to be a particular size.

Look into your group's constraints: Possibly select the image, then its size in the attributes inspector. It may need to be a fixed size in order to fit the labels into the upper section.

Otherwise the outer groups will not size to fit your content, they will only size large enough to fit the default space that is given for Glances in each section.